# SQLite using variable in LIKE query in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

All I want to do, user inputs full or partial Membership Number, and query the SQLite database.

The query will work if you use `LIKE %21%`, just can't use a variable.

```
$name=$_POST['mem_num'];

$db = new MyDB();

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM details WHERE MEM_NUMBER LIKE '%$name%' ');

while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    print $row["MEM_NUMBER"] . "\n";
}
```

I can do this is MySQL in seconds, but not in SQLite!

Comment: I dont know why but this question made me smile. and bang!

Comment: BANG and the dirt is gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE MEM_NUMBER LIKE '%" . $name . "%'");
```

How about this?

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry mate how do i do that ?

Comment: Just put your mouse pointer on the 2 triangles above and the green check will appear. Click on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM details WHERE MEM_NUMBER LIKE "%'.$name.'%" ');
```

You need to concatenate your query and your variable using dots and to put the percent signs as a part of the strings.

Comment: Adding an explanation always helps avoid random people flagging answers for deletion.

Comment: Cheers Mate top draw :)

Answer (score 0):

To use variables in PHP string, you need to enclose it in double quotes `"SELECT ... LIKE '%$name%'"`